# Laravel angularjs http post returns null from input

Tags: http, post, angularjs, laravel

I recently started to study angular js.
I am a bit lost with the http post, no matter what do i do i always get back null from the input

angular controller

```
function regCtrl ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.regSubmit = function() {
        $http.post(siteUrl + 'regisztracio', [{'felhasznalonev': $scope.felhasznalonev}]).success(function( data ){
              alert(data.msg);
        });
    }
}
```

laravel conroller

```
public function post_index()
    {
        $input = Input::json();
        $input_array = (array)$input;

        $rules = array(
            'felhasznalonev' => 'required'
        );

        $val = Validator::make($input_array, $rules);

        if(! $val->fails() ) {
            $data = array('msg' => 'all good');
        } else {
            $data = array('msg' => $val->errors->all());
        }

        return Response::json($data);
    }
```

form

```
<?php Section::start('content') ?>
<div class="content" ng-controller="regCtrl">


    <form class="span5 no-float centered" ng-submit="regSubmit()">

    <label for="felhasznalonev">Felhasználó név</label>
        <input type="text" id="felhasznalonev" name="felhasznalonev" ng-model="felhasznalonev" class="span5">

    <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="span5">

    <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="nem">Férfi
    </label>

    <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" name="nem">Nő
    </label>

    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="feltetel"><a href="" title="">Elfogadom a felhasználói feltételeket</a>
    </label>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-block">Regisztráció</button>

    </form>

</div>
<?php Section::stop() ?>
```

could please someone give me a hint what i am doing wrong? i have been mesing with it 3 hours now

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, digged in to the documentation more deelply

submit function looks like this

```
$scope.regSubmit = function() {
       $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: siteUrl + 'regisztracio',
            data: {felhasznalonev: $scope.felhasznalonev},
       }).success(function(data){
            alert(data.msg)
       });
    }
```

works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

I think you were close. Your $http just needed some changing.

```
function regCtrl ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.regSubmit = function() {
        $http.post(siteUrl + 'regisztracio', {
           felhasznalonev: $scope.felhasznalonev
        }).then(function(data){
              alert(data.msg);
        });
    }
}
```